# How to Design a Good Object-Oriented Structure

Tags: c#, oop

I just signed up for my first OO class in college and am a little lost right now. I am to create an inventory management system in UML and am stuck on where to place certain methods. I have a Transaction class and it is my understanding that a class should encapsulate all methods and attributes that work on a particular set of data. So, if I have an InventoryManager class that wants to get all the transactions, I imagine my Transaction class should have a method that says something like GetAllTransactions and return a List. But how can my Transaction class return a list of itself? See UML text representation of my TransactionManager and Transaction classes and how I think it would look in code. Method named to convey my intention for this question. **Can someone show me conceptually how this should be designed?**

| TransactionManager |
| --- |
| private List transactions |
| public List GetAllTransactionsFromTransactionClass(); |

| Transaction |
| --- |
| private string transactionId |
| Date date |
| private double price |
| public void Transaction() {} |
| public List GetAllTransactions(); |

If I create a local variable of a list of transactions (to return) in my GetAllTransactions method, isn't that going to cause a circular reference or something like that when I create a new transaction each time?

```
public TransactionManager
{
    public GetAllTransactionsFromTransactionClass
    {
        List<Transaction> transactions = Transaction.GetAllTransactions();
    }
}

public Transaction 
{
    public Transaction()

    public List<Transaction> GetAllTransactions()
    {
        List<Transactions> transactions = new List<Transaction>();
        transactions.add(new Transaction());

        return transactions;
    }
}
```

Comment: *how can my Transaction class return a list of itself* and what would be the point of that? The `Transaction::GetAllTransactions` as it is designed now is clearly a design mistake and without a more detailed context, it's even difficult to correct the mistake. The only correction I have at hand is remove this method completely. In an actual application the transaction manager would query a database or a network resource so you don't have to provide any implementation in your UML model.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, that is why I am asking the question. I am unsure how to design such a OO system. I thought a class is supposed to have ALL methods and attributes that operate on itself? Since GetAllTransactions sounds like it goes in the Transaction class, I put it there but then started questioning it. I just do not understand it.

Comment: A class should encapsulate all the methods relating to logic _internal_ to the class. Therefore it usually doesn't make sense for a class to have methods returning itself, although there are occasionally exceptions. GetAllTransactions in your example might go into some class that contains either the transactions or a way to access them (e.g. web call), although in the former case a readonly property might make more sense.

Comment: @Traveller, internal to the class, that makes sense. So anything that will change the data should be in the class? Otherwise, it should be in some other class.

Comment: Scott, you basically rewrote your question without even referring to my comment. You were told what to do, remove the method from the transaction class.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I did not want to be told what to do. I wanted to understand why my way was wrong.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I am in my first OO class. I want to understand it, not just complete it.

Comment: If you'd have the Bread class, would Bread bake itself? No, you need the Bakery. Bread can be eaten, sold etc. Is this a good analogy?

Comment: @WiktorZychla, that is a great analogy. Thank you. That makes much more sense. I believe I can now get back to my design and make something much better.

Comment: Part of the problem here is that you try to think in classes while you should start with a domain model. The domain model is also expressed in a class diagram but you are not allowed to have methods and inheritance. Instead you only have attributes and associations. You learn to think about responsibility.